# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on my recursive C function?

Tags: c, recursion, memory

This code is a college assignment. I'm supposed to write a recursive function that will return the largest consecutive sum in an array.

This is what I have so far:

Parameters:

- x = memory adress to the array
- sfm = memory adress to the max suffix sum
- n = size of the array

Returns: maximum consecutive sum of the array

```
double rsubMax(double *x, double *sfm, int n)
{
    n -= 1;
    double globalMax;
    double auxSfm = 0;
    double aux;

    if (n == 0)
    {
        auxSfm += x[n];
        globalMax = auxSfm;
    }
    else
    {
        aux = rsubMax(x, sfm, n - 1);
        auxSfm = *sfm;
        if (auxSfm + x[n] > aux)
        {
            auxSfm += x[n];
            globalMax = auxSfm;
        }
        else if (auxSfm + x[n] > 0)
        {
            auxSfm += x[n];
            globalMax = aux;
        }
        else
        {
            auxSfm = 0;
            globalMax = aux;
        }
    }
    *sfm = auxSfm;
    return globalMax;
}
```

When I try to run it on some tests, I get:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

I'm not very used to the debugging tool, but when I try to use it, it gives me a segmentation fault on the line right after the first 'else'.

I believe the function's logic is correct. I just barely know anything about memory allocation.

Comment: Make sure the recursion is terminating. Stack overflow is one reason for segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you really need to do `n -= 1;`? The recursive call passes `n-1`, so it's already decremented. You're decrementing twice. If the original `n` was odd, you'll skip over `0`, so the base case test `if (n == 0)` will never suceed.

Comment: `rsubMax(x, sfm, n - 1);` is wrong. You'e already (questionably) decremented `n` at inception. That should be `rsubMax(x, sfm, n);`

Comment: @Barmar You're right, thank you. I did it with the intention of the user passing the actual size of the array without it being out of bounds. 

I kept the 'n -= 1' and passed 'n' to the recursive call instead of 'n - 1' and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you again!

Comment: Consider creating an answer post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `n -= 1;`

When you decrease n = 0 will use second branch if like this

```
aux = rsubMax(x, sfm, -1);
```

Remove decreasing n, it could help

Comment: Let me explain this error: you stop recursion when n == 0, but it will never happen